# Can I automatically add Tasks to the Timeline

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, task-list

I am trying to setup a task list in SharePoint 2013 that will automatically add new tasks with start and end dates to the timeline.

Has anyone had any luck with this?  I looked around at creating a workflow to do so,  but could not find the features to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/3a0c76fb-f900-4c06-be41-300664a07ef4/adding-to-timeline-automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options to derive at a solution. They are,

Using JavaScripts
Using an Event Receiver

1. **Set required properties in the tasks list**

In the RootFolder of a particular Tasks list, there are three properties relevant to the Timeline control. When we create the list, those properties are not automatically set. As a result we have to set those three properties, namely,

TimeLineDefaultView

TimeLineAllViews

TimeLine_TimeLine

**- Get xml document in TimeLine_TimeLine property, and add required nodes**

We have to add xml nodes to “tskSet” and “mlSet” sections to represent the task which is to be displayed in Timeline control.

here is code:

```
var web = properties.Web as SPWeb;
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var taskList = web.Lists[properties.ListId];
var root = taskList.RootFolder;

if (root.Properties["Timeline_Timeline"] == null)
{
 //Add timeline related properties
root.SetProperty("TimelineDefaultView", "Timeline");
root.SetProperty("TimelineAllViews", "Timeline");
 //Add default xml to Timeline_Timeline property
root.SetProperty("Timeline_Timeline",@"<TLViewData><fmtSet><fmt id='0' clr='FFEE2222' thm='0001' t1='0' t2='1' type='0' /><fmt id='1' clr='FFEE2222' thm='0001' t1='2' t2='3' type='1' /><fmt id='2' clr='FFEE2222' thm='0001' t1='4' t2='5' type='2' /><fmt id='3' clr='FFEE2222' thm='0001' t1='6' t2='7' type='3' /></fmtSet><fltSet><ft id='{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}' uid='4294967295' uidSrc='1' onTL='0' fmt='1' y='4294967282' x='0' h='20' /></fltSet><tskSet><t id='{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}' uid='4294967295' uidSrc='1' onTL='0' fmt='0' ch='4294967295' /></tskSet><options dateFormat='255' panZoomT='9' ProjSummFmt='3' showDates='1' showProjSummDates='0' showToday='1' showTS='1' timelineHeight='133' timelineWidth='-1' timescaleT='8' todayT='10' /><mlSet>
<m id='{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}' uid='4294967295' uidSrc='1' onTL='0' fmt='2' y='35' x='0' /></mlSet><txtSet><style id='0' type='0' clr='FFEE2222' thm='0001' sz='8' font='Segoe UI' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='1' type='1' clr='FFEE2222' thm='0001' sz='8' font='Segoe UI' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='2' type='2' clr='FF999999' thm='0001' sz='8' font='Segoe UI' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='3' type='3' clr='FFB3B3B3' thm='0001' sz='8' font='Segoe UI Light' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='4' type='4' clr='FF525051' thm='0001' sz='10' font='Segoe UI' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='5' type='5' clr='FFB3B3B3' thm='0001' sz='8' font='Segoe UI Light' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='6' type='6' clr='FF999999' thm='0001' sz='9' font='Segoe UI' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='7' type='7' clr='FF999999' thm='0001' sz='8' font='Segoe UI' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='8' type='8' clr='FF999999' thm='0001' sz='8' font='Segoe UI' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='9' type='9' clr='FFFFA614' thm='0001' sz='8' font='Segoe UI Semibold' bold='1' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /><style id='10' type='10' clr='FFFFA72B' thm='0001' sz='10' font='Segoe UI Semibold' bold='0' ital='0' und='0' strk='0' /></txtSet></TLViewData>");
root.Update();
}

doc.LoadXml(root.Properties["Timeline_Timeline"].ToString());

//Create required xml nodes
var tElement = doc.CreateElement("t");
tElement.SetAttribute("id", "{" + properties.ListItemUniqueId.ToString() + "}");
tElement.SetAttribute("uid", properties.ListItemId.ToString());
tElement.SetAttribute("uidSrc", "1");
tElement.SetAttribute("onTL", "1");
tElement.SetAttribute("fmt", "0");
tElement.SetAttribute("ch", "4294967295");

var mElement = doc.CreateElement("m");
mElement.SetAttribute("id", "{" + properties.ListItemUniqueId.ToString() + "}");
mElement.SetAttribute("uid", properties.ListItemId.ToString());
mElement.SetAttribute("uidSrc", "1");
mElement.SetAttribute("onTL", "1");
mElement.SetAttribute("fmt", "2");
mElement.SetAttribute("y", "35");
mElement.SetAttribute("x", "0");

//Add created nodes to xml document
doc.SelectNodes("/TLViewData/tskSet/t")[doc.SelectNodes("/TLViewData/tskSet/t").Count - 1].AppendChild(tElement);
doc.SelectNodes("/TLViewData/mlSet/m")[doc.SelectNodes("/TLViewData/mlSet/m").Count - 1].AppendChild(mElement);
root.SetProperty("Timeline_Timeline", doc.OuterXml);
root.Update();

base.ItemAdded(properties);
```

http://dinushaonline.blogspot.com/2014/08/programmatically-add-tasks-to-timeline.html